# Why unable to push git local repo on github?

Tags: git, github

I am trying new to software development and git/github and trying to push a local repository on github and getting the following error..

**Error:-**

- PS C:\Users\akcai\OneDrive\Desktop\PollingApplication> git push -u
  origin master
  To https://github.com/atharvamishra123/polling_application.git
  ! [rejected]        master -> master (fetch first)
  error: failed to push some refs to
  'https://github.com/atharvamishra123/polling_application.git'
  hint: Updates were rejected because the remote contains work that you
  do
  hint: not have locally. This is usually caused by another repository
  pushing
  hint: to the same ref. You may want to first integrate the remote
  changes
  hint: (e.g., 'git pull ...') before pushing again.
  hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for
  details.

**command which i run are in the following manner:-**

- PS C:\Users\akcai\OneDrive\Desktop\PollingApplication> history
  Id CommandLine
  -- -----------                                                                                                                                                       1 cd OneDrive
  2 cd Desktop
  3 ls
  4 cd PollingApplication
  5 ls
  6 git init
  7 git add .
  8 git commit -m "initial_version_complete"
  9 git remote add origin
  https://github.com/atharvamishra123/polling_application.git
  10 git push -u origin master

please help i am unable to figure out what is the correct way to push local git repo on github.

Thanks in advance

Hope to here from you soon

Comment: Always search for existing questions first (see [ask]) - if you had put , e.g.,`Updates were rejected because the remote contains work that you do` into the search box, you'd get dozens of these.

Comment: Side note: in Git, commit messages are human readable, so please feel free to use spaces and descriptive messages (instead of messages like "initial_version_complete"). [Here's one popular example.](https://chris.beams.io/posts/git-commit/)

Answer (score 1):

First you need to do "git pull". Then "git push origin master"

This happens because the most recent changes to the reference must be updated before pushing